# Mongo Spark Connector - Date Filter

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read from mongo collection, and need to apply the filter while reading the dates,

e.g. sample mongo-query will look like :

```
db.mongo_coll.find( {dataDate :{$gte:ISODate("2021-01-01")})
```

how can I apply this in the spark-mongo read ?

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").
                           option("spark.sql.caseSensetive", "true").
                           option("sampleSize",3000).
                           option("url", ${hostConn}).load()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please try in this way.

```
val pipeline = "{'$match':{'dataDate':{'$gt':{'$date':'2021-01-01T00:00:00Z'}}}}"

val df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("spark.sql.caseSensetive", "true").option("sampleSize",3000).option("pipeline",pipeline).option("url", ${hostConn}).load()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
String match_query = "[{'$match':{'dataDate':{'$gt':DATE}}}]";
                spark.
                .read()
                .format("mongo")
                .option("uri", "{URI}")
                .option("collection", "{Collection}")
                .option("database","{DATABASE}")
                .option("pipeline", match_query)
                .load();
```

Comment: Your answer can be improved by explaining what your code is doing.